# Dúvida com arquivos htaccess

Tags: htaccess

estou com uma dúvida a respeito de uma configuração no meu arquivo .htaccess.

Tenho uma página com o seguinte nome:

```
 gastronomia.php
```

Daí em meu arquivo inclui a seguinte linha para torná-lo amigável:

```
RewriteRule ^gastronomia$ gastronomia.php
```

Até aí tudo bem:

O problema é que, eu criei uma subpasta em meu site para hospedar o mesmo conteúdo no formato mobile.

Daí então, dentro da pasta "mobile", há também um arquivo com o mesmo nome - gastronomia.php.

Neste caso, como que configuro o meu arquivo .htaccess de forma que torne possível eu utilizar também uma url amigavel neste arquivo dentro da subpasta?
Ou seja, digitar  www.site.com.br/mobile/gastronomia

Abçs.

Comment: Cria o .htaccess dentro da pasta mobile também.

Comment: Blz, deu certo. obgd amigo =D